# Passing parameters - Shell

Tags: shell

Suppose i have a folder(F1) with below files,

```
WIreport_614.log
WIreport_615.log
boecms12.log
boecms13.log
```

Now i have a code like below to fetch some unique parameters from above files using a script,

```
$HOME/findexceptions_bo.pl < .log >> $HOME/exceptions.log
```

So my need is to pass the .log files from F1(n number of files) one by one and run the above script like below,

```
$./script.sh
$HOME/findexceptions_bo.pl < WIreport_614.log >> $HOME/exceptions.log
$HOME/findexceptions_bo.pl < WIreport_615.log >> $HOME/exceptions.log
```

Please let me know how to pass it and execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the files one at a time:

```
for file in /folder/*.log; do
    $HOME/findexceptions_bo.pl < "$file" >> $HOME/exceptions.log
done
```

Or concatenate all of the log files together and process them all at once, if that'll work for you.

```
cat /folder/*.log | $HOME/findexceptions_bo.pl >> $HOME/exceptions.log
```

Comment: Change `/folder/*.log` to point to your directory. `/folder/` is just an example.

Comment: Actually i used folder name itself as "folder".Please help